# bash: if block fo if env var is not empty

Tags: bash, shell

In the below example, `else` block is for if env var is not empty. i would like for it to go to `if then` block

```
if [ -z "$var" ]
then
      echo "\$var is empty"
else
      echo "\$var is NOT empty"
fi
```

would it be negating the if block?

```
if ! [ -z "$var" ]
then
      echo "\$var is empty"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can invert like this :

```
if ! [ -z "$var" ]
```

or

```
if [ ! -z "$var" ]
```

or even better using bash test :

```
if ! [[ -z $var ]]
```

or

```
if [[ -n $var ]]
```

or even simply

```
if [[ ! $var ]]
```

`[[` is a bash keyword similar to (but more powerful than) the `[` command. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals. Unless you're writing for POSIX sh, we recommend `[[`.